# Markov chains by hand

Tags: probability, matrices, statistics, markov-chains

If I have a starting point: $A_T=[0,1]$ at $T=1$ and a one step transition matrix of:
$B=\left[ \begin{align} &\frac34 & \frac14& \\& \frac1{20}& \frac {19}{20} &\end{align} \right]$

I can compute $A_nB=A_{n+1}$
And keep reiterating this, but it is slow by hand, I assume there is a faster way? Would diagonalizing the matrix help somehow?

Comment: Yes, if you diagonalize it as $B = PDP^{-1}$, then $B^n = PD^nP^{-1}$, and $D^n$ is the matrix obtained from (the diagonal matrix) $D$ by taking the $n^{\text{th}}$ powers of the diagonal elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$B$ can be diagonalized as $B = PDP^{-1}$, where
$P = \begin{bmatrix}-5 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, $P = \begin{bmatrix}7/10 & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, $P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}-1/6 & 1/6\\1/6 & 5/6\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $B^n = PD^nP^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}-5 & 1\\1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}(7/10)^n & 0\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-1/6 & 1/6\\1/6 & 5/6\end{bmatrix}$.

$$\boxed{\therefore B^n = \dfrac{1}{6}\begin{bmatrix}
5\left(\dfrac{7}{10}\right)^n + 1 & 5 - 5\left(\dfrac{7}{10}\right)^n\\
 1 - \left(\dfrac{7}{10}\right)^n &     \left(\dfrac{7}{10}\right)^n + 5
\end{bmatrix}}$$

As $B$ is a right stochastic matrix (because the row sums are $1$, not the column sums), we need to right multiply by $B$:

$A_n = A_0 B^n = \begin{matrix}[0 \quad 1]\\\mbox{} \end{matrix} \times
\dfrac{1}{6}
\begin{bmatrix}
5\left(\dfrac{7}{10}\right)^n + 1 & 5 - 5\left(\dfrac{7}{10}\right)^n\\
 1 - \left(\dfrac{7}{10}\right)^n &     \left(\dfrac{7}{10}\right)^n + 5
\end{bmatrix}\\
\mbox{}\\
\boxed{A_n = \dfrac{1}{6}\left[1 - \left(\dfrac{7}{10}\right)^n \qquad     \left(\dfrac{7}{10}\right)^n + 5\right]}$

Comment: Can I obtain a specific number of iterations using this method? Say I wanted $A_T, T=4$? Am I taking $n=4$?

Comment: @DisplayName Yes, check the updated answer. I was adding that part when you commented.

Comment: That all makes sense, thank you for that explanation. One final query: When diagonalizing are you just doing this via eigenvalues and eigenvectors, or is there a faster way in this case?

Comment: @DisplayName An alternative way is to start with $A_n = BA_{n-1}$, carry out the multiplication on the RHS to get two recurrence relations (one for each component of the vector $A_n$), and then solve the recurrence relations using standard formulas. I think this should take as much effort as finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors, if not more, because it is essentially the same method, and only looks different.

Comment: Thank you for your help once again M. Vinay, I believe that is the fourth question you have helped me with, keep up the good work!

Comment: @DisplayName I'm extremely sorry, I didn't notice earlier that the transition matrix is right stochastic. So you need to multiply it on the right, not the left. And the state vector is a row vector. Again, sorry about not noticing it before. Only while answering https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838559/applying-transition-matrix-to-a-probability-vector-seems-to-ruin-its-normalizati now did I suddenly remember that I hadn't checked the matrix for your question. All the parts of the answer concerning the matrix itself are correct. Only $A_n$ (the last part) was wrong. I have corrected it.

Comment: Very nice, thank you for that, now I know more about the problem, no worries at all!