# Applying transition matrix to a probability vector seems to ruin its normalization

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, markov-chains

I had a little bit about stochastic processes during my "Statistical Physics" course and on my exam I got a problem with a Markov chain. My solution seems to be without computational mistakes (checked it with Mathematica), so I suspect some deeper misconception, because the components of my probability vector don't add up to 1 after my calculations. Below I present the problem and my solution. I'll be grateful for any suggestions.

A 2 state particle is initially in a state $P(0)=(1,0)^T$. It's transition matrix is:

$$
T = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
5/6 & 1/6 \\
2/6 & 4/6 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Calculate the probability of the particle being in its second state after 5 steps.

My solutions in the following:

- find the eigenvalues $(1$, $\frac{1}{2})$ and their respective eigenvectors $((1,1)^T$, $(1,-2)^T)$
- find the $P'(0)$ (initial probability vector's representation in $T$'s eigenvector basis):

$$
P'(0)=\beta^{-1} \cdot P(0) =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2/3 & 1/3 \\
1/3 & -1/3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{array}{c}
2/3 \\
1/3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

- calculate $P'(5) = T'^5\cdot P'(0)$:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & (1/2)^5 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2/3 \\
1/3 \\
\end{array}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{array}{c}
2/3 \\
1/96 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

- return to the original basis with $P(5) = \beta \cdot P'(5)$:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -2 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\cdot
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
2/3 \\
1/96 \\
\end{array}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{array}{c}
65/96 \\
62/96 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Now, as I understand the vector $P(5)$ gives us 2 probabilities: one, of the particle being in state A after 5 steps ($65/96$), and second, of the particle being in state B after 5 steps ($62/96$). But those are the only two options, so those numbers should add up to 1. So what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$T = \begin{pmatrix}5/6 & 1/6\\ 2/6 & 4/6\end{pmatrix}$ is a right stochastic matrix (see the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix), for example). So you need to *right*-multiply the state vector (which is a row vector rather than a column vector as you have given) with $T$. This gives, for example:

$(1\quad 0)\begin{pmatrix}5/6 & 1/6\\ 2/6 & 4/6\end{pmatrix} = (5/6\quad 1/6)$ (whereas $T(1 \quad 0)^T$ gives $(5/6 \quad 1/3)$, which is not a state vector).

Similarly, $(1 \quad 0)T^5 = (65/96 \quad 31/96)$.